# Maven project java unable to import dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

[image]

I am unable to import the dependencies as shown in the screenshots. What am i doing wrong here. Please help thank you.

Comment: can you upgrade your java version from 1.5 to 1.7 or 1.8

Comment: Without the compilation error messages, it is hard to guess. Your IDE mentions **12** compilation errors.

Comment: Check your maven configuration. Are you using the bundled one that came with intellij or your own installation?

Answer (score 0):

Above your `<dependencies>` section, add the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then **right click on your project -> Maven -> Reimport**. This will reconfigure the compiler for language level (instead of default 1.5 which is much too low), and more importantly import the libraries in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

try 
right click the project
1.configure-->convert to maven project
2.Maven--->update maven project-->force update of snapshots and releases